# How to automatic set the size of html layout?

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone I'm new with this format on how to automatic set the design of html.

Here in my PC it works properly even the design is fine, no destruction of format or layout, but when I'm working with another PC, the format was broken.

It has a white background even before my picture background and format was damage.  My computer monitor is 18 inches and the another one laptop is 23 inches.

I try my self to locate what is the problem but I don't know the best solution for that.

What code should i put to be able work properly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>IT Course SUPPLIES</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="iicon.jpg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap2.js">
    <script src="bootstrap1.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" ><font color="#FF0066">IT COURSE SUPPLIES</font></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">First Year <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="1.html"> Analytic Geometry: with more Applications and Special Topics</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.html">Differential Equations: A Simplified Approach</a></li>
                <li><a href="3.html">Basic Calculus</a></li>
                <li><a href="a.html">Simplified Approach to Integral Calculus</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">2nd Year <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="4.html">Crimping Tool</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.html">RJ45 + RJ11 Cable Tester</a></li>
                <li><a href="6.html">RJ45 Toolless Jacks</a></li>

                <li><a href="8.html">Discrete Mathematics 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="9.html">General Statistics for College Students: Text/Workbook</a></li>
                <li><a href="10.html">CISCO CERTIFIED CCNA Routing and Switching Laboratory Manual</a></li>
                <li><a href="11.html">CAT5E Network Cable</a></li>
                <li><a href="12.html">RJ45 heads</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">3rd Year <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="13.html">Rizal Prose</a></li>
                <li><a href="14.html">Rizal's Poems</a></li>


              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <style>
      body { 
        background-image: url('12.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 200px 50px; 
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      div.absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top:  100px;
        right: 400px;
        width:500px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="absolute">
      <h1>about IT Online Course store</h1>

      <p>
        IT Online Course online store delivers digital products to your door.<br>
        You can now get the latest high-tech products delivered straight to your door with IT Online Course.<br>
        You can also choose from a new range of products and services ideally suited to meet <br>
        the needs of the modern traveler.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find the code [Here](http://pastebin.com/Xbc0YPbB)
Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you.

Comment: Hi Kenny, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/Xbc0YPbB here is my code @Error404

Comment: oh thanks man..sorry for bad format @Pete

Comment: You have two `body` tags and the `style`  tag must be in `head`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the screen resolution for multiple screen resolution, you got to go with media-queries where you can code your website layouts to fit mobile, tab, desktop, large screen...

**1.Media Queries**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    ul li a {
        padding-left: 30px;
        background: url(email-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

**2.Bootstrap**
Here bootstrap framework helps in predefined classes which also gives you

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp